# call api with Retrofit JAVA

Tags: java, android

hi i have an api and i want to call it but it seems to be failing.

[linkapi](https://iotapi.levanphuc.asia/api/v1/device/1)

my api has form `https://iotapi.levanphuc.asia/api/v1/device/id`

i want to call api to do a PUT method if status is 0 when on press on then stustus turns to 1 and shows success

I have tried several ways with no success

I don't know if anyone can explain to me where I did wrong. Any help is very welcome

my code
ApiService

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("{id}/pin")
    Call<Device> getDeviceStatus(@Path("id") String id);

    
    @PUT("{id}")
    Call<Device> turnOnDevice(@Path("id") String id);

   
    @POST("{id}/pin/0")
    Call<Device> turnOffDevice(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

mainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ApiService apiService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://iotapi.levanphuc.asia/api/v1/auth/device/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        apiService = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);

        Button btnTurnOn = findViewById(R.id.btn_turn_on);
        btnTurnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOnLight(1);
            }
        });

        Button btnTurnOff = findViewById(R.id.btn_turn_off);
        btnTurnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOffLight(String.valueOf(1));
            }
        });

    }

    private void turnOnLight(int id) {
        apiService.turnOnDevice(String.valueOf(id)).enqueue(new Callback<Device>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Device> call, Response<Device> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "light turn on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "light turn on error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Device> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error connect API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    private void turnOffLight(String deviceId) {
        apiService.turnOffDevice(deviceId).enqueue(new Callback<Device>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Device> call, Response<Device> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "light is turn off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error turn off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Device> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error connect API", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Device

```
 private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private int pin;
    private int status;
    private String createdAt;
    private String updatedAt;
```

Comment: Check have you added internet permission in manifest secondly check the error by logging t.message in failure case. In case you cant resolve the mention the error in post